# Error NU1101 : Package WebEid.Security missing

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, eid

I am trying the WebEid dotnet example you can find here : https://github.com/web-eid/web-eid-asp-dotnet-example

I completed the quick start steps but when I tried "dotnet build" step, I have an error :

> error NU1101 : Unable to find package 'WebEid.Security'. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget, nuget.org, web-eid.js

I understand that it miss this package but the example project is supposed to be complete, and I can't find this package anywhere.
I open an issue last week, but no answer at all.

So I hope someone here can help me because it's for my work in internship, and I am kind of stuck here.

Thank you so much

EDIT : I found the WebEid.Security in another github repository : https://github.com/web-eid/web-eid-authtoken-validation-dotnet/tree/main/src/WebEid.Security
But I can't find how to use it to make my project works.
I tried to publish it to obtain a dll file, but still not working. I tried add the file emplacement into the package manager, still not working.
Maybe I do something wrong doing it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it myself.
I build the WebEid.Security.cs and then it add a file .nupkg into the bin folder.
I use that bin folder in the package manager of the example project and it builds.